# How can I set up STM32CubeIDE for collaborative projects?

Tags: git, stm32, collaboration, stm32cubeide

STM32CubeIDE is used for writing firmware for STM32 MCUs.
Previously, we shared projects through export/import of projects and sharing include files/folders.

This is quite cumbersome. I'm sure STM32CubeIDE is used by larger teams where they have to work together and share a large codebase. How can we implement a similar workflow?

Comment: Why don't you consider using a version control system? BTW, there is also an Eclipse plugin named *DevStyle* which provides something called *CodeTogether*, but I've never tried it.

Comment: Can you please recommend a version control system? Our current process includes sharing latest copies of the entire project, and backing up older copies before overwriting. This is a cumbersome manual process at the moment.

I will look up DevStyle on eclipse. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Eclipse has a very good git support.

Answer (score 2):

> How can we implement a similar workflow?

By using [Git](https://git-scm.com/) as a version control system, and [GitHub](https://github.com/) or [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) as centralized repository hosting service.

You can see on GitHub STM32CubeIDE-related projects like [`ethanhuanginst/STM32CubeIDE-Workshop-2019`](https://github.com/ethanhuanginst/STM32CubeIDE-Workshop-2019)